# Separate the first loop append and the second loop append while doing double loop in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops

Now I am trying to make two dimesional array with double loop.

In my code:

```
for t in range(0,150):
    for z in range(0,279):
            QC1 = QC[t,z,:,:]
            SUMQ =1000*np.mean(QC1)
            QRAIN1.append(SUMQ)
    print len(QRAIN1)
    QRAIN.append(QRAIN1)
    QR = np.array(QRAIN)
```

I would like to make 150X279 array, but the result is not, because I think that in every time of the first loop run, the results are appended in the QRAIN1.

I would like to separate each loop run of the list of 259 numbers and accumulate them to QRAIN resulting 150x279 array.

Any help or idea would be really appreciated.

Thank you,

Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a new empty list each time through the loop:

```
for t in range(0,150):
    QRAIN1 = []
    for z in range(0,279):
        QC1 = QC[t,z,:,:]
        SUMQ =1000*np.mean(QC1)
        QRAIN1.append(SUMQ)
    print len(QRAIN1)
    QRAIN.append(QRAIN1)
QR = np.array(QRAIN)
```

BTW, any time you find yourself starting with an empty list and then appending to it in a `for` loop, consider the stylish alternative of a **list comprehension**:

```
for t in range(150):
    QRAIN1 = [1000*np.mean(QC[t,z,:,:]) for z in range(279)]
    print len(QRAIN1)
    QRAIN.append(QRAIN1)
QR = np.array(QRAIN)
```

I'm also removing the redundant `0,` in the `range` calls -- again just a matter of style, but I like Tufte's principle, "no wasted pixels":-)

Of course you could also build all of `QRAIN` with a **nested** list comprehension, but I understand that's starting to be a bit of a stretch, and the "middle way" of a listcomp inside, a `for` loop outside, may be considered more readable.  Anyway, just in case you want to try...:

```
QRAIN = [ [1000*np.mean(QC[t,z,:,:]) for z in range(279)]
          for t in range(150) ]
QR = np.array(QRAIN)
```

This one doesn't have the `print`s but I suspect you were only using them as a debugging aid, so their loss shouldn't be a big problem, I hope:-).

Comment: Thank you Alex! I missed that point. I will try with your advice.